# GameCenter: "The connection to service named com.apple.gamed was interrupted"

Tags: ios, game-center

I get this error message

> The connection to service named com.apple.gamed was interrupted, but
>   the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy
>   has become invalid.

sometimes when calling

```
loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error)
```

What does it mean?

I'm on iOS 9.3.2

Answer (score 0):

This is the worst possible answer, but it's my own experience with loading matches, I'm sorry to say: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I've received this error message before, and then had it go away after no code changes at all. Just try again.

Comment: My weird comment on this message is that I get it (with an exception code -10877) when trying to connect an Audio Unit Extension to a running `AVAudioEngine`. Also the problem occurs "sometimes", in 1 of 20 cases or so. Wonder if it's some internal RPC issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I have more findings. Forget my comment to the other answer.

In my case I got the message when I did not use the `@escaping` keyword on a closure parameter of a function (using Swift 3 where closures are by default non-escaping). This function was called with a closure that did not refer to `self` (because it was not needed). However, that function called another function, forwarding the closure.
So in the end my closure ended up without a reference.
I recommend you keep a copy of your block that you use as an argument to `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler`. This way the block is not released prematurely.

This also explains why the error occurs just sometimes and not always. It's typical for memory release issues.